# Retrieve data from PostgreSQL Database using ADO.Net "System.Data.Odbc" (VB.Net)

Tags: postgresql, unicode, ado.net, odbc

Though I have been using SQL Server, Oracle from last decade, I have been asked to 
do some research on PostgreSQL and after some initial investigation it is evident that I am now stuck on retrieving data from the PostgreSQL database using Function.

Using following piece of code to retrieve the data and getting error 
('ERROR [26000] ERROR: prepared statement "mytabletest" does not exist;
            'Error while executing the query)

*Code Snippets*

```
    Dim oDBCommand As DbCommand = GetDBCommand(oConnectionType, "mytabletest", CommandType.StoredProcedure)
    Dim dstResults As DataSet = GetDataSet(ConnectionTypes.ODBC, oDBCommand)


Public Function GetDataReader(dbType As ConnectionTypes, command As DbCommand) As DbDataReader

    Try

        Dim oConnection As DbConnection = GetDBConnection(dbType)

        Dim oDBTransaction As DbTransaction = oConnection.BeginTransaction
        command.Connection = oConnection
        command.Transaction = oDBTransaction


   'GETTING ERROR ON FOLLOWING LINE
        'ERROR [26000] ERROR: prepared statement "mytabletest" does not exist;
        'Error while executing the query
        return command.ExecuteReader()


    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    Finally
    End Try

    Return Nothing

End Function
```

Environement I am currently working on is following:-

```
32 Bit Machine. 
Visual Studio 2010 + SP1 
ODBC Prodiver: PostgreSQL Unicode 9.01.02.00
ADO.Net (System.Data.Odbc)
```

**Please note that I am open to any suggestions i.e. if I am completely doing it wrong
OR partially etc. Please feel free to write.**

In order to make it easier for you to create a same environment, please use following table/function definition.

```
--- Simple table to make things easier to understand. <br>
CREATE TABLE mytable
(
  messagetypeid integer NOT NULL,
  messagetype character varying(100) NOT NULL
)
```

```
-- Function to retrieve data. <br>
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mytabletest()  <br>
   RETURNS SETOF refcursor AS $$
    DECLARE 
    ref1 refcursor; 
    BEGIN
      OPEN ref1 FOR SELECT * FROM mytable;
      RETURN NEXT ref1;                                                                               
    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

***Please Note:***

```
If I use <br>
  Dim oDBCommand As DbCommand = GetDBCommand(oConnectionType, "SELECT * FROM mytable", CommandType.Text)
```

then system manages to retrieve information from the datbase without any issue, however, as I mentioned as soon we use "Function" it throws an exception.

During my failed efforts to search any solution from the internet someone mentioned that Table should be created with the lower case it so just for the sake of it I recreated with the lower case, however, problem persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unfamiliar with `.net` but I suspect you meant something more like:

```
GetDBCommand(oConnectionType, "SELECT myfunc()", CommandType.Text)
```

Or in the case of `SETOF` functions etc..

```
GetDBCommand(oConnectionType, "SELECT * FROM myfunc()", CommandType.Text)
```

PostgreSQL does not have 'stored procedures' per-ce. It does have `functions` and I believe that the client/server protocol has a method for preparing statements that can then be executed multiple times with different variables (to save on the cost of parsing the SQL), but this should be exposed via your client library.

Comment: Chris, you are a star!!
Thank you so much for your efforts to make it possible to work as intended.


This is not an excellent way of passing function definition to
Command object, however, I guess we do not have any choice but to
use how you suggested. I have spent almost a day to get to where I am now :(  They did not make it easier for Developer in this particular instance.

Once again, thank you so much for your input. Much appreciated.